# How can compare 2 elements of each pair in the Arraylist(Java)

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface Pair

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface Pair<T,M> {
    public T getFirst();
    public M getSecond();
    public ArrayList<Pair<T,M>> Compare(ArrayList<Pair<T,M>> list);
}
```

and an class called MatchingPairs that implement the Pair interface:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MatchingPairs implements Pair<Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer getFirst() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getSecond() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>> Compare(ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>> list) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I dont know how to compare the first element and the second element of each pair by implementing the compare method.

Comment: Why does the _element_ class `MatchingPairs` (name seems odd though) contain a method for comparing lists of those? And whats the problem with getting elements at the same index, getting first and second for both elements and comparing those?

Comment: Your method `Compare()` seems really weird to me. Please provide some example data and result of the method. Explain what it is supposed to produce. Usually I'd expect a `Pair` to implement a `Comparable` interface, that is have a `compareTo` method, where you compare this instance of `Pair` to another `Pair` and that would return boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish with the Compare method. But here is an example of comparing two lists of MatchingPairs using the Comparable interface.

```java
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public interface Pair<T,M> extends Comparable<Pair<T,M>> {
        T getFirst();
        M getSecond();
    }

    public static class MatchingPairs implements Pair<Integer, Integer> {

        private final Integer first;
        private final Integer second;

        public MatchingPairs(int first, int second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getFirst() {
            return first;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getSecond() {
            return second;
        }

        /**
         * Returns 0 if both first and second are equal in this and the other object
         * Returns 1 if both first and second are greater in this object ('this' is greater than 'other')
         * Otherwise return -1 ('this' is less than 'other')
         */
        @Override
        public int compareTo(@NotNull Pair<Integer, Integer> other) {
            int cf = this.getFirst().compareTo(other.getFirst());
            int cs = this.getSecond().compareTo(other.getSecond());
            if (cf == 0 && cs == 0) {
                return 0;
            } else if (cf > 0 && cs > 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MatchingPairs{first=" + first + ", second=" + second + '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MatchingPairs> pairs = List.of(new MatchingPairs(2,3), new MatchingPairs(1,2), new MatchingPairs(1,1));
        MatchingPairs find = new MatchingPairs(1, 2);
        // collect all pairs that are greater than 'find'
        List<MatchingPairs> matching = pairs.stream()
                .filter(mp -> mp.compareTo(find) > 0)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(matching);
    }

}
```

The exact implementation of the compareTo method may be different for you, as you did not specify the exact behaviour that you are trying to implement.
In the main method we create a list of MatchingPairs and then collect all the MatchingPairs from this list that are greater than a specified instance of MatchingPairs.